# Displaying Vector Value

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to add all of the values of my vectors together and get the average, but im receiving error messages.

Here's my directions fo the assignment so you guys could better understand

1)      Accept 15 grades into the vector from the user

EXTRA ADVANCED challenge and requirements:

Accept the number if and only if it is greater than 0.00. Accept the number if and only if, it is a valid type double. That is you are doing validation in this manner each time before populating the values into the vector?

2)      After the numbers are accepted into the vector, calculate and display the average of the 15 entered numbers.

3)      Using Bubble Sort (or another method/algorithm native to vectors), sort the 15 numbers in the array from Greatest to Least. Hint: does not a vector have a built-in sorting method? How do we get the vector to sort descending as required here rather than the standard acending?

4)      Display the sorted gradesVector

Here's the error messages:

```
main.cpp:43:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'sum'
     sum = accumulate(gradesVector[i].begin(), gradesVector[i].end(), 0);
     ^
main.cpp:43:42: error: member reference base type 'value_type' (aka 'double') is not a structure or union
     sum = accumulate(gradesVector[i].begin(), gradesVector[i].end(), 0);
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
main.cpp:43:67: error: member reference base type 'value_type' (aka 'double') is not a structure or union
     sum = accumulate(gradesVector[i].begin(), gradesVector[i].end(), 0);
                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
main.cpp:44:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'average'
     average = sum/15;
     ^
main.cpp:44:20: error: use of undeclared identifier 'sum'
     average = sum/15;
               ^
main.cpp:46:18: error: use of undeclared identifier 'average'
     cout << average;
```

Here's the code:

```
vector<double> gradesVector;
gradesVector.reserve(15);


for(vector<double>::size_type i = 0; i < 15; i++)
  {
    int c=0;       
do
  {

    if(c!=0)   

      cout << "Invalid Rage. Please Enter Range 0-100:\n";         
      cout << "Please Enter Grade "<< i + 1 <<": " << flush;
      cin >> gradesVector[i];
      c++;   
  }
    while(gradesVector[i] < 0.0 || gradesVector[i] > 100.0);

     sum = accumulate(gradesVector[i].begin(), gradesVector[i].end(), 0);
     average = sum/15;

     cout << average;

        }
```

Comment: Define the variables the compiler's asking for. Initializing them to 0 is highly recommended.

Comment: Your error messages say that the errors are on lines 43, 44, and 46 of your program, but the code in your question is only 25 lines long.  Missing code aside, have you looked carefully at those lines to see what the problem is?

Comment: When you are done defining the missing variables, look up the difference between `vector::reserve` and `vector::resize`. Also worth reading up on Range-Based `for` loops.

Comment: @user4581301 i declared the variables now i get this error message `main.cpp:47:42: error: member reference base type 'value_type' (aka 'double') is not a structure or union
         sum = accumulate(gradesVector[i].begin(), gradesVector[i].end(), 0);`

Comment: i changed the vector to  `vector<double> gradesValue(15)`

Comment: `gradesVector[i]` is an element in the vector, not the vector. You want to call begin on the vector not a double stored in the vector.

Comment: thanks that helped me out a lot  i forgot to use `#include <numeric>` to use the `accumulate()` function

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**This is the answer**

I forgot to use `#include <numeric>`

the code now reads

```
vector<double> gradesVector(15);
double sum;
double average;

for(vector<double>::size_type i = 0; i < 15; i++)
  {
    int c=0;       
do
  {

    if(c!=0)   

      cout << "Invalid Rage. Please Enter Range 0-100:\n";         
      cout << "Please Enter Grade "<< i + 1 <<": " << flush;
      cin >> gradesVector[i];
      c++;   
  }
    while(gradesVector[i] < 0.0 || gradesVector[i] > 100.0);
```

This line of code uses `#include <numeric>` I also changed `gradesVector[i].begin()`and`gradesVector[i].end()`
    to `gradesVector.begin()` and `gradesVector.end()`

```
     sum = accumulate(gradesVector.begin(), gradesVector.end(), 0); 
     average = sum/15;



        }
cout << average;
```

Comment: Edit your original question, don't post your updates in a non-answer.

Comment: Think over that `if (c!=0)`. It's going to work, but the lack of braces and the indentation of the following lines is a bit of a mind freak.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: I think that this code actually answers the question, at least partly, so it should not have been an update to question.

Comment: ok thanks i will delete the answer and just update the answer

Comment: It is fine to answer your own question, and it well received to do it when you could build an answer from comments. But you should make it **explicit** that it is an answer.

Comment: Keep this, but explain what you changed and why so other people can learn from it.